# Prolog ask a question and resolve by dependency comprehension question

Tags: prolog

i am new in Prolog and fighting me through examples.

Now I would write a simple program by having different sentences.

1. dolly is a sheep
2. dolly is not a pig
3. every animal on farm is a pig or goat
4. every sheep is an animal

statement that I would have is : dolly is a goat

so I wrote some Code:

```
is(not dolly,pig).
is(X,goat).
is(X,pig).
animal(X):-is(X,goat);is(X,pig).
sheep(X):-animal(X).
```

Maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
I can't get my statement.

Thank you
Greetings

Edit1:
After reading and reading I am confused.
I write a second snippet.

```
sheep(dolly).
pig(not(dolly)).
goat(dolly).
animal(X):-goat(X);
    pig(X).
animal(X):-sheep(X).
```

but after that I don't get my statement anyway

dolly is a goat

Edit 2: Answer Questions From Will Ness

how do you write this down?

sheep(dolly).

I think my question is What  animal is dolly.

and my answer should be goat
Hopefully I got your point.

Edit 3: try to get the comment

exactly

?- animal(X,dolly).

X=Goat

Comment: "dolly is a sheep". how do you write this down? in other words: decide what query do you want to perform, what answer do you want it to give to you, and then you can decide, how to achieve that. that's what it means "to code the statement 'dolly is a sheep'". so how do you answer these questions?

Comment: well, thx for your comment. I thought I give simple facts and rules and through unification prolog will answer me dolly is a goat--> cause all animals are goats or pigs

Comment: you're theorizing, but I asked you concrete questions. write down the answers please, one by one to the questions I asked. they are intended to guide you on a constructive path. edit them into the question, then we could try answering it!

Comment: I mean, write them down exactly as you'd like them to appear at your Prolog prompt.